# Как добавить интернет к VPN серверу на Raspberry PI

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi, wireguard

Установил WireGuard VPN по [инструкции](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-wireguard/). Могу подключиться к VPN, но нет интернета. Что делать?

Comment: скорее всего вам необходимо настроить `iptables` добавив новый рул с `MASQUERADE`, это можно добавить в конфигурацию `wireguard`

Comment: @exploding-kitten А Вы бы могли написать настройку `iptables`, если у меня такие настройки: VPN  IP: 10.6.0.1, Gateway 10.0.0.1(Internet router) и DNS 10.0.0.20. Спасибо.